# How to assert a task was restarted at least once

Tags: c#, unit-testing, task

I am test driving a class that gets injected with a bunch of work tasks, runs the asynchronously and restarts them when completed until told to halt all tasks.

Since I am doing test first I needed to write a test that forces me to write the restart logic, and I have kind of successfully done this, but I don't think I did it very well.

Test code: (`FakeTask` is basically a test spy that keeps track on whether it was called and how many times)

```
[Fact]
public async void Start_GivenTask_RerunsTaskUntilStopped()
{
    var agent = CreateKlarnaAgent();
    var fakeTask = DoNothingTask();

    agent.Start(fakeTask);
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    await agent.Stop();

    Assert.True(fakeTask.TimesRun > 1);
}
```

(Relevant) production code:

```
public void Start(params IWorkTask[] workTasks)
{
    _logWriter.Debug("Starting...");
    _tasks = workTasks
        .Select(workTask => workTask.DoWork().ContinueWith(task => OnTaskComplete(task, workTask)))
        .ToArray();
}

private void OnTaskComplete(Task completedTask, IWorkTask workTask)
{
    if (completedTask.IsFaulted)
    {
        foreach (var exception in completedTask.Exception.InnerExceptions)
        {
            _logWriter.Error("Unhandled exception thrown!", exception);
        }
    }
    else workTask.DoWork().ContinueWith(task => OnTaskComplete(task, workTask));
}

public Task Stop()
{
    return Task.WhenAll(_tasks)
        .ContinueWith(t => { _logWriter.Debug("Stopped"); });
}
```

The test is now really depending on a race condition and it doesn't feel like a unit test at all. How can I get rid of the `Thread.Sleep(500)` call? Or is this simply something I should test in an integration test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a side note, I recommend against writing "task runners" in general, and also recommend against `ContinueWith` in particular since it is such a dangerous API.

In my opinion, the "repeat forever until canceled" logic is far more clearly expressed using a loop for "repeat" and a cancellation token for "canceled":

```
static async Task WorkAsync(Func<Task> doWork, CancellationToken token)
{
  while (true)
  {
    await doWork();
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  }
}
```

However, that said, if you want to unit test your "task runner" as-is, you'll need to make your `FakeTask` more intelligent. For example, you could have it set a signal when it reaches a given count and have your unit test wait on that:

```
class FakeTask : IWorkTask
{
  private readonly TaskCompletionSource<object> _done = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
  public Task Done { get { return _done.Task; } }
  public Task DoWork()
  {
    ++TimesRun;
    if (TimesRun > 1)
      _done.TrySetResult(null);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }
}

[Fact]
public async Task Start_GivenTask_RerunsTaskUntilStopped()
{
  var agent = CreateKlarnaAgent();
  var fakeTask = DoNothingTask();

  agent.Start(fakeTask);
  await fakeTask.Done;
  await agent.Stop();

  Assert.True(fakeTask.TimesRun > 1); // spurious test at this point
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Regarding the WorkAsync method, I understand that you would recommend making the tasks themselves responsible for repeating themselves then? Do you have any insights to offer regarding the ups and downs with the different approaches, or could you point me to some other resource where it is discussed? All in all, your suggestion with awaiting the fakeTask, while a little itchy because the test double is getting almost a little too complex, feels a lot better than my current approach. Marking as accepted, thanks :)

Comment: @kai: I have an aversion to "task runners". They're often complex and prone to have odd corner cases (for example, the code you posted is using `ContinueWith` in a very dangerous way, making its semantics depend on its execution context). Putting logic into code instead of a "code runner" is both clearer and less likely to be wrong.